# ¿Cómo aplicar la siguiente función a un diccionario cuyos valores son listas de listas?

Tags: python-3.x, lista, lógica

Tengo el siguiente diccionario:

```
    "dict": {
        "HN": [[4.3, 4.3, 4.75, 5.20], [2, 2, 2.3, 2.6],[1, 1, 1.74, 2.47],[0.1, 0.1, 0.4,0.7]],
        "MN": [[4.75, 5.20, 5.20, 5.65], [2.3, 2.6, 2.6, 2.9],[1.74, 2.47, 2.47, 3.21],[0.4, 0.7, 0.7, 1]],
        "SN": [[5.20, 5.65, 5.65, 6.1], [2.6, 2.9, 2.9, 3.2], [2.47, 3.21, 3.21, 3.95], [0.7, 1, 1, 1.3]],
        "Z": [[5.65, 6.1, 6.1, 6.55],[2.9, 3.2, 3.2, 3.5],[3.21, 3.95, 3.95, 4.68],[1, 1.3, 1.3, 1.6]],
        "SP": [[6.1, 6.55, 6.55, 7],[3.2, 3.5, 3.5, 3.8],[3.95, 4.68, 4.68, 5.42],[1.3, 1.6, 1.6, 1.9]],
        "MP": [[6.55, 7, 7, 7.45],[3.5, 3.8, 3.8, 4.1],[4.86, 5.42, 5.42, 6.16],[1.6, 1.9, 1.9, 2.2]],
        "HP": [[7, 7.45, 7.9, 7.9],[3.8, 4.1, 4.4, 4.4],[5.41, 6.16, 6.9, 6.9],[1.9, 2.2, 2.5, 2.5]]
    }
```

Cuyo formato es el siguiente:

```
"label": [ X1, X2, X3, X4 ]
```

Digamos que es como una especie de matriz, la columna de listas del diccionario son los X1, la segunda los X2 y así hasta X4

El tema está en que debo de aplicar una función de membresía a las Xi de este diccionario.

La lista element será el parámetro de entrada

```
element = [ 5.1, 3.8, 1.6, 0.2]
```

Para cada elemento de la lista hay que aplicar la siguiente función:

```
def membership_function(u, alpha, beta, gamma, delta):
    if u < alpha:
        return 0
    elif alpha <= u < beta:
        return round((u - alpha)/(beta - alpha), 1)
    elif beta <= u <= gamma:
        return 1
    elif gamma < u <= delta:
        return round((gamma - u)/(delta - gamma), 1)
    elif u > delta:
        return 0
```

Alpha, beta, gamma y delta serán los elementos de cada una de las listas del diccionario. Por ejemplo: [ 4.3, 4.3, 4.75, 5.20] serían estos elementos, y u = 5.1

El resultado esperado es que para cada elemento de element, busque en las posiciones de la lista de listas de los valores de las claves y se calcule una lista de listas de elementos de 7 posiciones, con valores tal que [ 0 0.9 1 0.3 0.4 0 0].

El objetivo final de esta lista es obtener la etiqueta del diccionario en la posición del valor máximo, por ejemplo:

```
resultado = ['HN', 'MN', 'SN', 'Z']
```

No se si si hay alguna otra forma mejor de poder organizar la información, simplemente es como lo he pensado inicialmente, cualquier otra sugerencia posible la agradecería enormemente. El proceso que estoy intentando llevar a cabo se conoce como "fuzificación" de determinadas variables, para el conjunto de datos flor-iris.

Comment: Hola Christian, los parámetros de la función de membresía son u y alpha beta gamma y delta, u es cada uno de los elementos iterables en la lista element y el resto de parámetros serían x[0], x[1], x[2] de cada Xi de los valores del diccionario

Comment: ya pude entender eso, pero no me queda claro de donde sale `u`, ademas en base a que quieres obtener esos valores maximo?, los 4 primero? los que tengan el mismo valor? o que?